# how do i extract data from notepad file and put into specific row in csv using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a notepad file and an csv file. I want to extract the "new_password" data from the notepad file and paste it into the password column in the csv file using python. Please refer the attached files and help me with the code in python. I was successful in writing the entire text file contents in the password column in csv file but i want only the new_password data into csv file.

```
import csv

f1 = open ("format.txt","r") # open input file for reading
for i in f1.readlines()[1:]:
        if ';' in i:
            temp=i.split(';')
            f1 = temp[1]

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f: # output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    with open('passwords_sample.csv','r') as csvfile: # input csv file
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:  
            row[4] = f1.readlines() # edit the 8th column 
            writer.writerow(row)
f1.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, to understand we might need to see the data sample or  how do you determine `new_password`? .Considering first question you have done a great formatting.

Comment: @WoodChopper: I wanted to upload the files but i am unable to find how to do it...